# Proving two lines are perpendicular

Tags: complex-numbers

Given $z_1,z_2,z_3 $ and $z_4$ are complex numbers, prove that the line joining $z_1,z_2$ and the line joining from $z_3,z_4$ are perpendicular iff $Re\{(z_1-z_2)(\bar z_3-\bar z_4)\}=0$. Try not to use polar form.

I try to start with writing $Re\{(z_1-z_2)(\bar z_3-\bar z_4)\}=Re\{z_1\bar z_3\}-Re\{z_1\bar z_4\}-Re\{z_2\bar z_3\}+Re\{z_2\bar z_4\}$ (I'm not sure if it's right)

Then how can I make use of the perpendicular condition? Any hints for the reverse direction, or I just have to reverse the argument?

Thank you!

Comment: If $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal vectors then $v\cdot w=0$. This is the definition of [orthoganility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality).

Comment: how do we define dot product on a complex plane? And why do we have to take conjugate of $z_3$ and $z_4$?

Comment: The euclidean dot product on $\Bbb C^n$ is defined as $$v\cdot w:=\sum_{k=1}^n v_k \bar{w}_k$$ See the definition and characteristics of any dot product [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition).

Answer (score 1):

Let $w=z_1-z_2$ and $v= z_3-z_4$. The given $Re(w\bar{v})=0$ leads to

$$w\bar{v}+\bar{w}v=0$$

Then, evaluate

$$|w-v|^2= (w-v)(\bar{w}-\bar{v})
=|w|^2+|v|^2-(w\bar{v}+\bar{w}v)= |w|^2+|v|^2$$

which means $w$, $v$ and $w-v$ form a right triangle, hence $w$ and $v$ are perpendicular to each other. The reserve also holds, i.e.
$$|w-v|^2= |w|^2+|v|^2\implies w\bar{v}+\bar{w}v=0\implies Re(w\bar{v})=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z_1-z_2=ae^{i\theta}$ and $z_3-z_4=be^{i\phi}$, then

$$(z_1-z_2)\overline{(z_3-z_4)} = abe^{i(\theta-\phi)}$$
$$\operatorname{Re}[(z_1-z_2)\overline{(z_3-z_4)}] = ab\cos (\theta-\phi)$$
\begin{align*}
  \operatorname{Re}[(z_1-z_2)\overline{(z_3-z_4)}]=0
  & \iff \cos (\theta-\phi) =0 \\
  & \iff \theta-\phi=\left(n+\frac{1}{2} \right) \pi \\
  & \iff (z_1-z_2)\perp (z_3-z_4)
\end{align*}

where $a$, $b> 0$